# Excel: Moving a Table Row to Another Sheet's Table

Tags: excel, vba

Not very experienced with Excel coding, but I got a decent way myself. But I cant figure this thing out.

Looking to automate a sheet so that when a cell in column E is set to "Staffed", the macro will move the entire row from the table in Sheet A to the Table in Sheet B. At the moment, the macro is placing the cut and pasted row below the table, sometimes 20 something rows below, on the new sheet.

I would appreciate the help. Thank you

```
Sub NtS()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    
    I = Worksheets("Clients Needing Staffed").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Clients Staffed").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Clients Staffed").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Clients Needing Staffed").Range("E1:E" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Staffed" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Clients Staffed").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Staffed" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `On Error Resume Next` like that... that's hiding potential errors. If you want this to run automatically, perhaps look at the [`Worksheet.Change` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

Comment: Also I'm not a fan of copy and pasting with VBA. Where in Sheet B is it meant to go? In the first empty position? Or the same row as it was in sheet A?

Comment: Adding to what @BigBen mentioned, problem with using `UsedRange` is that it includes all cells that have ever been used in that sheet (i.e. lets say that your last row with data in your sheet is 10. But you had something on row 20 in the past. Your `UsedRange` will return the row count as 20 even though to the naked eye, 10 rows are populated). Try this to get the value for `I` (and `J`): `Worksheets("Clients Needing Staffed").Cells(Worksheets("Clients Needing Staffed").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. Although you could make that statement a lot smaller if you qualify your sheet or use `With`

Comment: I found the code online, and adjusted it as best I knew how to what I needed. So the first Sheet is "Clients Needing Staffed" and the 2nd sheet is "Clients Staffed". The row in Sheet B its suppose to go is just a new empty row in the table. Hopefully this is helpful, sorry I am very inexperienced.

Comment: I tried the code below and its moving it to the 2nd row of the new sheet, which is the sheet header. Also if another row is moved, it pastes it on top of the one previously moved. If two or more are moved, it moves fine. Example: I move 1 and 2, they paste in (still on 2nd row start, over the sheet header). Then I run the macro again to move 3. 3 will then cover up 1, and 2 will still remain.

Comment: Try setting `Const tgtFirstRowCol As Variant = "E"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy and Delete Rows (Union)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NtS()
    
' Constants
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Clients Needing Staffed"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const srcLastRowCol As Variant = "E" ' e.g. 1 or "A", 5 or "E"...
    Const srcCritCol As Variant = "E" ' e.g. 1 or "A", 5 or "E"...
    Const srcCriteria As String = "Staffed"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Clients Staffed"
    ' The following parameter has to be 1 or "A", because copying entire row.
    Const tgtFirstCol As Variant = "A" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const tgtFirstRowCol As Variant = "A" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook with this code.
    
' Source
    
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim srcLastRow As Long
    srcLastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, srcLastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If srcLastRow < srcFirstRow Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Define Criteria column range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = src.Range(src.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcCritCol), _
                                          src.Cells(srcLastRow, srcCritCol))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through each cell of Criteria column range to search
    ' for Criteria value.
    Dim cel As Range, uRng As Range, i As Long, k As Long
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = srcCriteria Then
            k = k + 1
            If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
                Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel.EntireRow)
            Else
                Set uRng = cel.EntireRow
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    If uRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Data has already been deleted.", vbExclamation, "Done Nothing"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
' Target
    
    ' Define Target First Row.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Dim tgtFirstRow As Long
    tgtFirstRow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.Count, tgtFirstRowCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Copy 'collected' range of rows to Target worksheet starting
    ' from Target First Cell.
    uRng.Copy tgt.Cells(tgtFirstRow, tgtFirstCol)
    ' Delete 'collected' range of rows.
    uRng.EntireRow.Delete
 
' Finish
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data copied and deleted.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```